# Compare two dates with Pipe Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, date, pipe

I use Angular CLI 6 , angularfire2 and firebase.

I want to compare two dates: StartDate and EndDate.

In English, if the month and year of start date = month and year of EndDate then do not display End Date.

I try this :

component.html :

```
<mat-list *ngIf="compareDates()">({{ ppsToDisplay?.datefin | date:'MMMM y'}})
Component.ts

compareDates(): boolean {
   return this.datePipe.transform(this.ppssToDisplay.datefin, 'MM-yyyy') === 
            this.datePipe.transform(this.ppssToDisplay.datedebut, 'MM-yyyy');
}
```

It is here that I can not write in the typescript to take into account the pipe. Thank you for your help

Comment: Which version of angular you're using?

Comment: i use angular 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your `compareDates` as below:

```
sameDates(): boolean {
   return datePipe.transform(this.StartDate, 'MM-yyyy') === 
            datePipe.transform(this.EndDate, 'MM-yyyy');
}
```

You will have to inject DatePipe in your component constructor.

```
constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe)
```

Also, you will have to add `DatePipe` to your component's providers list

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
```

You will have to import the angular common module in your app module.

```
import { DatePipe, CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [..., CommonModule, .... ],
  ...
```

Comment: HI think i have a problem in my condition because the ngif doestn' work correctly

Comment: @Newbiiiie What is the issue you are facing now?

Comment: Thank you to response. I haven't error but the ngif condition doesn't work. It does nothing.. Maybe it is my condition in template ?

Comment: It works fine - you may check the values of date fields and try.  The code I have shown does not check for null/undefined values - you may have to add necessary checks to make your code work

Comment: My data provides of an observable. I arrive to get my data only in template. It is possible to havre thé pipe directly in ngif?

Comment: If date is observable, then, you can try `yourDate | async | date:'MMMM y'`

Comment: This expression into the ngif condition directly in the template ?

Comment: I try this but it doesn't work : *ngIf="ppsToDisplay?.datedebut | date:'MMMM y' === ppsToDisplay?.datefin | date:'MMMM y'">